# Link the like button of my site to the FB like button

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've been trying to make my own social buttons. Everything worked fine for the sharing buttons. However, I can't have a good result with the FB like button. I created a SVG image with the thumbs up and I open a javascript popup window that shows the FB like button. It's not friendly user at all as the person has to click twice to like the content.

I'm trying to figure out a way to make my button likes directly on FB. Do you know if it is possible? I have seen sites that have their own like button like a "heart" button or something like that and once we click it makes also a like on facebook besides the site's like. Does anyone knows how to do it?

For the moment, the code is this one with the SVG image between the  tags:

```
<a href="javascript:popupFacebookLike('http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={{ url_public }}&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&height=80')"></a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/

Comment: Thanks. However, does it mean that I have to integrate facebook authentification in my website in order to have my own like button? I don't want to create barriers to my users that will have to authentify themselves and accept the link with my site before liking some content...

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, stick with the normal like button.